# Checking if the rank is the same - TSQL

Tags: t-sql, rank

I have written a code that retrieves details for orders placed by a customer and brings back the date it was placed on.

```
USE[tsql2012];
WITH CTE_1
AS
(
select 
    [ID] = customers.custid
    ,[Name] = contactname
    ,[OrderID] = orders.orderid
    ,[Order Date] = orderdate 
    ,[Date] = format(orderdate,'MMMM-yy')

from sales.orders
left join sales.OrderDetails   on OrderDetails.orderid = orders.orderid
left join sales.Customers      on orders.custid = customers.custid
)

select 
    [ID] 
    ,[Name] 
    ,[OrderID]  
    ,[Date]
    ,[Rank] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [DATE] ORDER BY [ORDERID])

FROM CTE_1
```

This is the code I get

```
ID  NAME                   ORDERID    DATE     RANK
10  Bassols, Pilar Colome   10492   April-07    1
10  Bassols, Pilar Colome   10493   April-07    1
```

How do I check if the `Rank` column contains more than 1 instance of the same ranking number, so if two orders were placed on the same day it should change the date column like so:

```
ID  NAME                   ORDERID    DATE      RANK
10  Bassols, Pilar Colome   10492   April-07(1)  1
10  Bassols, Pilar Colome   10493   April-07(2)  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time please share sample data, best provided as DDL with DML and your expected output.

Try something along this:

```
,CONCAT([Date], '(',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ID],[Date] ORDER BY [OrderId]),')') AS DateWithIndex
```

If I do not get something wrong, this should concatenate your given date with a running number partitioned by the grouping condition...